# In C++, is the name of objects(such as queue, map) reference(or pointer)?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, reference

I just a have a simple question. Give an example, in a function in C++:

```
queue<int> q1;
q1.push(1);
queue<int> q2=q1;
```

I know "q1" and "q2" themselves are just addresses(like a pointer,am I right?)possibly stored on stack while the real data is store on heap. So if I pop q2, will 1 appear?

Comment: I think you will be using the constructor syntax for q2. Hence, q2 will be a new queue with elements initialized to elements of q1. For reference, see this - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/queue/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know "q1" and "q2" themselves are just addresses(like a pointer,am I right?)possibly stored on stack while the real data is store on heap.

Assuming `queue` to be [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), when you write:

```
std::queue<int> q1;
```

you are effectively allocating an `std::queue` object. An object is a region of space in the memory. In this particular case, `q1` (as well as `q2`) is allocated using automatic memory; which means that it will be deallocated when the corresponding symbol goes out of scope.

Therefore, no: `q1` and `q2` are not simple pointers. A pointer is usually declared with type `T*` (for any `T`), which is not present in here.

---

> So if I pop q2, will 1 appear?

No, it won't. The [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/queue) of `std::queue`, called in:

```
std::queue<int> q2 = q1;
```

will perform a [*deep copy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy), leading to two unrelated `std::queue`s. What it means is that the region of space is ***not*** shared between the two objects `q1` and `q2`.

If you wish to do so, you can use references like this:

```
std::queue<int> q1;
std::queue<int>& q2 = q1;
```

In the above example, `q1` and `q2` refer to the same object.

Comment: Hi, you are right. But if I pop from q2, the value 1 should appear,right? What you mean is that popping from q2 doesn't affect q1,right?

Comment: @HaoShen, yes, in your example *popping* from `q1` doesn't affect `q2` and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

When you write : `queue<int> q1;`

**q1 is not address**, it's an object.
If you Do this

`auto q1 = new queue<int>();`

q1 will be an address i.e. a pointer to your newly created object. When you write: `queue<int> q2=q1;` you'd be calling the copy constructor i.e.

`queue<int>::queue(const queue<int>& src);`

to initialise the q2 object, so q2 will be the same thing as q1 i.e. an object not an address. (which may not internally points to the same heap area, where elements of q1 are stored)

About the second question: When you create

`queue<int> q1;`

**your object may allocate space for the elements which will be stored in heap**, because the container internally stores it's element by allocating memory dynamically.

About your last question:No, **If you pop something from** `q2`, **changes will not be reflected in `q1` as well.** If you want your changes to be reflected in q2 as well you have to create q2 as a reference of q1 i.e. `queue<int>& q2 = q1;`

Comment: *"If you pop something from q2, changes will be reflected in q1 as well."* -- No, definitely not.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i thought it'd be a shallow copy, fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

```
queue<int> q1;
```

This declares an automatic variable.  That is, `q1` is an actual object, not an address.  When `q1` goes out of scope, its destructor will be called automatically.

```
q1.push(1);
```

This will push an `int` into the queue with the value of `1`.  Internally, the queue will have a dynamic memory structure set up to hold the values, but that is transparent to you here.

```
queue<int> q2 = q1;
```

This will create a new automatic variable named `q2` and initialize it with a copy of everything in `q1`.  You can then call `front` on both `q1` and `q2` and both will return `1`.  If you call `pop` on `q1`, `q2` will still have `1` in it's queue.

Comment: pop doesn't return anything.